# Typescript parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a statement of code below. If I want to call this function in a useEffect hook, what should be my parameter in onLoginSubmit()?

`const onLoginSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)`

Comment: The `FormEvent` you received from the form. You need to elaborate more.

Comment: The `FormEvent` is receiving email, password, name and stuffs.